# What happens to running queries when a view is dropped?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, view, amazon-redshift

Curious to know what happens when you drop a view. Specifically, I'd like to know what happens to long-running queries executing against this view.

Will long running queries fail on the view's deletion?
Is the view's plan already in memory and not required to exist for long running queries?

I'm mainly interested in how Postgres (& Redshift) handle this scenario.

Comment: Have you tried to test it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

`DROP VIEW` must take an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the view.

Queries take an `ACCESS SHARE` lock on the view when they use it. `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` conflicts with this lock, so `DROP VIEW` will block until long running queries finish.

Try it and see, just open a couple of `psql` sessions. You will find it informative to examine `select * from pg_stat_activity sa inner join pg_locks l on (sa.pid = l.pid)`.